Nissan Almera N16 2006 No Crank No Start
So parked my car up after coming back from shopping 3 days ago. I accidently left the boot slightly open.
Today I got in the car tried to start it but it wouldn't crank/start at all. When the ignition is turned, a locking sound is heard (as if you lock the car). Then a humming sound for a few seconds. Also the car immobiliser warning light flashes on the dashboard.
I am hoping it is just the battery being flat and will check it once I get back from my appointment which I had to Uber to. I tried both my keys I own and neither worked.
